# get user list who likes facebook page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-php-sdk

I am working with codeigniter.

I want to get user list who likes facebook page,in page currently 675 likes but,from below code it shows me 6 likes only ,I am not sure this is correct way or not.

```
public function fetch_fb_fans($fanpage_name="pagename", $no_of_retries = 10, $pause = 500000 /* 500ms */){
    $ret = array();
    // prepare real like user agent and accept headers
    $context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header' => 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/49.0.2623.108 Chrome/49.0.2623.108 Safari/537.36\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch\r\nAccept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8,pl;q=0.6\r\n')));
    // get page id from facebook html og tags for mobile apps
    $fanpage_html = file_get_contents('https://www.facebook.com/' . $fanpage_name, false, $context);
    if(!preg_match('{fb://page/(\d+)}', $fanpage_html, $id_matches)){
        // invalid fanpage name
        return $ret;
    }
    $url = 'http://www.facebook.com/plugins/fan.php?connections=100&id=pageid';
    for($a = 0; $a < $no_of_retries; $a++){
        $like_html = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

        preg_match_all('{href="https?://www\.facebook\.com/([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)" data-jsid="anchor" target="_blank"}', $like_html, $matches);
        if(empty($matches[1])){
            // failed to fetch any fans - convert returning array, cause it might be not empty
            return array_keys($ret);
        }else{
            // merge profiles as array keys so they will stay unique
            $ret = array_merge($ret, array_flip($matches[1]));
        }
        // don't get banned as flooder
        usleep($pause);
    }
    echo"<pre>";print_r($ret);die;

}
```

can any one help me to get required result?

Comment: No, scraping Facebook pages is absolutely not the correct way - it is not allowed. And the list of users who like a page is not available via API.

Comment: please can you tell me how can I get that ?

Comment: he just told you that it is not allowed and not possible. there is no way. why would you need the list of users anyway? what for?

Comment: Is it possible with php sdk ,which help me to get list of user who likes my facebook page ?

Comment: please read the comments again. it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is the documentation of the plugin.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin

The connections param doesn't is accepted and no take effects.